# How to fix 'library is not defined' error in my react app

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I am getting 'library' is not defined  no-undef' error. I am trying to add font awesome in my app. I have write some code for this:

Error:

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/sections/header/header.js
>
> Line 11:  'library' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

## header.js code

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

 import {
   faGoogle,
   faFacebook,
   faTwitter,
   fainstagram
 } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

 library.add(
   faGoogle,
   faFacebook,
   faTwitter,
   fainstagram
 );
 class Header extends Component {
   render() {
    return (

   <div className="social-icons">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" className="facebook"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="fafacebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" className="twitter"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="fatwitter" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" className="instagram"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="fainstagram" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   )
  }
 }
```

## App.js Code

```
 import React from 'react';
 import logo from './logo.svg';
 import './App.css';
 import bootstrap from 'reactstrap';

 import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
 import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' 
 library.add(fab);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add library import since import is not globally accessible to other component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
 import {
   faGoogle,
   faFacebook,
   faTwitter,
   fainstagram
 } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

 library.add(
   faGoogle,
   faFacebook,
   faTwitter,
   fainstagram
 );
 class Header extends Component {
   render() {
    return (

   <div className="social-icons">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" className="facebook"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="fafacebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" className="twitter"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="fatwitter" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" className="instagram"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="fainstagram" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   )
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have added library as you guided. I found new error: ./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

Comment: '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'  can you verify this node module installe d properly

Comment: I have tried to reinstall fontawesome module. But I found this error: 

 @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Do you have typescript installed globally?

Comment: Thank you. Fontawesome is worked for fas icons. But still fab and far icons are not rendering